# Is it a good practice adding the CSRF token in redux store?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux, csrf-token, react-rails

Is it a good practice to store a CSRF token in redux? I was passing it with props before (to add it to Axios headers). I have a rails back end and I am using the gem `react-rails`, my components are server rendered, so I did not come up with any other way of doing so but passing the CSRF token to the component.

Comment: No, this is not a good idea, the main purpose of redux is to store long-life domain-specific values. `csrf-token` is an implementation detail. You can try to use `cookies` to keep csrf-token.

Comment: @ŁukaszOlszewski The problem is I can't use cookies with Server rendered components, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to store the token in your Redux store.

The purpose of the token is to prevent other sites/origins from making non-GET (POST, PUT, DELETE) requests to your API. Without it, a malicious site could make the request and piggyback on the cookies and session stored in your browser. In a plain HTML server-rendered Rails app, this token is put directly into the HTML, making it available to any JavaScript on that page. So, it's not private information for any code on the pages you control.

Nonetheless, given it's global nature and that you might need it outside of the context of Redux, it's probably best to put it on `window` for anyone to use:

```
window.CSRF_TOKEN = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content")
```

Any time you call `fetch`, you can include these headers:

```
headers: {
 'X-CSRF-Token': window.CSRF_TOKEN
}
```

Since you're using `react-rails`, you can also pass it to your component as props:

```
react_component 'MyForm', authenticity_token: form_authenticity_token
```

If you're not relying on Rails sessions for authentication (with a Bearer token, for instance), you can also disable the CSRF token entirely with this line in your `ApplicationController`:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```